# NSInvalidArgumentException when sending local notification from AppDelegate

Tags: ios, swift, uilocalnotification

I want to open specific view when user taps on received notification when app is in the background. I am posting a notification from appDelegate like this:

```
    func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveLocalNotification notification: UILocalNotification) {
    if let info = notification.userInfo {
        // Check if value present before using it
        if let s = info["CallIn"] {
            if(s as! String == "10minBeforeMeeting"){
                NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("EventListShouldRefresh", object: self)
            }
            if(s as! String == "CallInNotification"){
                if let UUID = info["UUID"]{

                    print("ha: \(UUID)")
                    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("OpenDetailViewOfMeeting", object: self, userInfo: ["UUID":UUID])
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            print("no value for key\n")
        }
    }
    else {
        print("wrong userInfo type")
    }
}
```

In the class, that is observer for this notification I have:

```
//in viewDidLoad:
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "openDetailView", name: "OpenDetailViewOfMeeting", object: nil)




func openDetailView(notification: NSNotification) {
    let userInfo = notification.userInfo as! [String: AnyObject]
    let UUIDunbind = userInfo["UUID"] as! String

    let events = CalendarController.sharedInstance.todaysMeetings()
    for event in events {
        if(event.UUID == UUIDunbind){

            let detailViewController = DetailViewController()
            detailViewController.meeting = event

            self.mainViewController.showDetailViewController(detailViewController, sender: self)
        }
    }
}
```

When I get the notification I get the NSInvalidArgumentException:
seems like it does not even go inside the method openDetailView. In other place I am using exactly the same structure and it works (although there notification is posted not from appDelegate, but directly from some class). 
Error log:

** *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[CallIn.ViewController openDetailView]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f9623c4d330'**

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: : is missing in selector method like - selector: "openDetailView:"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing a `:` at your selector structure, which represents the argument `notification` from your `openDetailView` method.

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "openDetailView:", name: "OpenDetailViewOfMeeting", object: nil)
```

Should you require more information on it, you can find the documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithObjective-CAPIs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH4-ID59).